# Generic Array - can't compile

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get an array of hashmaps and here's what I have:

```
public class MinCuts {

HashMap<Integer, Integer> [] graph;         // Graph as an array of hash maps
int size;                                   // Number of nodes

// Empty constructor
MinCuts() {

} // END OF CONSTRUCTOR


// Reads the graph from file path as an adjacency list
public void openFile (int num_of_nodes, String path) {
    In in = new In(path);
    graph = (HashMap<Integer, Integer> []) new Object[num_of_nodes];

    String adj_list;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_nodes; i++) {
        adj_list = in.readString();
        StdOut.println(adj_list);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    MinCuts x = new MinCuts();
    x.openFile(10, "/Users/alekscooper/Desktop/kargerMinCut.txt");

}
```

I'm aware that you need to do casting when having an array like this but still it won't compile. I can't understand what the problem is. Please, help.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't compile? A line like `graph = (HashMap<Integer, Integer> []) new Object[num_of_nodes];` should compile but throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Comment: don't use generic array - java cannot properly handle it (yet). use raw `HashMap[]`; or just `Object[]`. do casting when you are forced to.

Comment: This is what I get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.util.HashMap;
 at MinCuts.openFile(MinCuts.java:21)
 at MinCuts.main(MinCuts.java:35)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 ...

Sorry, I'm a beginner, I misused the word 'compile'. What should I do? –

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a `ClassCastException` because an `Object[]` is not a `HashMap[]`.

You *can* solve it by writing:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void openFile (int num_of_nodes, String path) {
    In in = new In(path);
    graph = (HashMap<Integer, Integer> []) new HashMap[num_of_nodes];
```

**I do not recommend this** (written in bold because I normally get downvoted when I write `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in an answer).

A better solution is to use a `List<Map<Integer, Integer>>`. Generics and arrays do not go well together.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your `graph` like this: `Map<Integer,Integer> [] graph = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();` 
Much like declaring an `ArrayList` object when you would say `List l = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: `new HashMap<Integer,Integer>()` isn't an array.